# How can I use ListView inside a CarouselView?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to show data from my ObservableCollection named "Stats". It works good when I use this code:

```xml
<ListView
    Style="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Stats}"
    HasUnevenRows="true">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

But when I try to place this into the CarouselView like that:

```xml
<CarouselView>
     <CarouselView.ItemTemplate >
         <DataTemplate >
             <ListView
                Style="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Stats}"
                HasUnevenRows="true">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
             </ListView>
         </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

It shows nothing. How can I use ListView inside?

Comment: you don't have an ItemsSource defined for your Carousel

Comment: Should I move my ItemsSource from ListView to CarouselView or it should be another source?

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to accomplish.  Do you want to replace your listview with a carousel?  Or do you want your LIstView to be one page within the carousel?

Comment: I want to show ListView inside the Carousel

Comment: So what do you want to happen when the user rotates to the next page of the Carousel?

Comment: Firstly, i`m trying to learn how to place it here. When it will work I create another page.

Comment: your Carousel needs an ItemsSource that will be a `List<List<T>>` (or something like that).  Then your ListView's ItemsSource will be the inner `List<T>` that is the current context of the Carousel.  You should be able to bind the ListView's `ItemsSource="{Binding .}"`

Comment: @Sergey Hi, if you have solved it, remember to mark the answer when you have time , it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your Carousel needs an `ItemsSource` that will be a `List<List<T>>` (or something like that). Then your `ListView`'s `ItemsSource` will be the inner List that is the current context of the Carousel. You should be able to bind the ListView's `ItemsSource="{Binding .}"`